# how to use mysql's FIND_IN_SET in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a simple mysql datatable like this:

```
users:
user_id score
1          0
2         20
3       1430
4        820
5        170
```

Im using the following mysql query to get the rank of a user with a certain user_id:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET( score, (
                    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
                        ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                    FROM users )
                ) AS rank
                  FROM users WHERE user_id = 4
```

and in my mysql it returns me correctly

```
rank
2
```

because user_id=4 has the 2nd highest score here.

But how does the corresponding query look like in nodejs? 
My copy-paste code returns an error:

```
var query = connection.query('SELECT FIND_IN_SET( score, (
                    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
                        ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                    FROM users )
                ) AS rank
                  FROM users WHERE user_id = 4', function(err, result){
    console.log(err);
});
```

with the error:

```
    var query = connection.query('SELECT FIND_IN_SET( score, (
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Comment: thx, but this was just another copy-paste error. I actually dont have "users" in the query. Edited the query in the question. Error is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiline strings in JavaScript without escaping the line returns or using [ES6 template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Try

```
var query = connection.query("SELECT FIND_IN_SET( score, (\
                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score\
                    ORDER BY score DESC ) \
                FROM users )\
            ) AS rank\
              FROM users WHERE user_id = 4", function(err, result){
console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: multiline queries work for other queries in my nodejs script. I will try it out now tho..

Comment: oh, it worked. And after having a closer look, I noticed I didnt have any multiline strings in the script yet. So thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my answer if it solved your issue. You can also take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript), it contains alternatives that may interest you. :)

Comment: On SO, you have to wait a couple of minutes after asking a question for accepting an answer

Comment: Oh OK, didn't know that